# Simple LiveCD running only Xorg Server

Tags: livecd, x-server

I have a netbook without HDD, I think it could be useful for monitoring logs.
Do someone know about a light LiveCD, running only a Xserver?

Comment: Should it be _really_ lightweight? What's the hardware in netbook? If you want to use it for a longer time maybe better solution will be some distro installed on USB stick (not LiveUSB).

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out about http://www.slitaz.org:

- Root filesystem taking up about 100 MB and **ISO image of less than 30 MB.**
- Ready to use Web server powered by LightTPD with CGI and PHP support.
- Browse the Web with Midori or Retawq in text mode.
- Sound support provided by Alsa mixer, audio player and CD ripper/encoder.
- Chat, mail and FTP clients.
- SSH client and server powered by Dropbear.
- Database engine with SQLite.
- Generate a LiveUSB device.
- Tools to create, edit or burn CD or DVD images.
- Elegant desktop with Openbox **running on the top of Xorg/Xvesa (X server).**
- Homemade graphical boxes to command line utilities.
- 2300 packages easily installable from the mirror.
- Active and friendly community.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Tiny Core Linux: http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/welcome.html

It runs in 10M of memory, and has a very sparse install. If you want to go even lighter, you can use Micro Core, which is basically Tiny Core with X, and weighs in at 6M.

If you grab the MultiCore cd, you'll get both systems on the cd.